# (gdb)print pointer and printf("%p",pointer) gives different adresses

Tags: c, gdb

```
int main(){  
int value = 25;  
int *pointer = &value;  
printf("value = %d\n",value);  
printf("pointer = %p\n",pointer);  
printf("&pointer = %p\n",&pointer);
```

When I execute this program, It prints 25 for *value*, `0xbffff834` for *pointer* and `0xbffff830` for *&pointer*. However when I use GDB to debug this program and type `break 6`(refers to the line `printf("value" = %d",value);`)  and type `print pointer`, GDB gives me the result `0xbffff824`. It also gives me `0xbffff820` when I type `print &pointer`. Shouldn't the addresses that the debugger gives and the program prints be the same? If they don't have to be, can you explain why not? When I type `x/d pointer` to the debugger, it gives me 25 (which is correct by the way). My question is not why are `pointer` and `&pointer` are different, it is why do the same pointer(the pointer named `pointer` in this case) stores different adresses when I run the program with the command `./deneme`(the name of my program is *deneme*, and when I debug the program using the the gdb debugger. I used the command `gcc -g -o deneme deneme.c` to compile my program. The program works succesfully both on the debugger and with the`./deneme` by the way.

Comment: Because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), maybe?

Comment: Btw `%p` format specifier expects  argument of type `void *` otherwise it causes  undefined behavior.

Comment: within the same execution, it should print the same. Between runs, it's a different story.

Comment: `printf("&value = %p\n",&pointer);` i think there is a typo but i don't know what you want to do with it

Comment: The very last `printf("&value = %p\n",&pointer);` is somewhat redundant. Is this your _actual_ code?

Comment: I just wanted to see what `printf("&value = %p\n",&pointer);` prints. But yes it is redundant and not really relevant with the solution so I am deleting it from the question.

Comment: I think ASLR is turned off on GDB by default.

Comment: What are the compiler-flags? If you use optimization, the bets are off... Also, try `print (void *)pointer` in gdb.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the error?

Comment: I wrote a similar program `char a = 'a';  char *b = &a;  printf("%p",b);`. It printed 0xbffff837 to the console. When I debugged it with gdb and typed `print b` it again gave 0xbffff827. Which again is exactly 10(on base 16) lower than the printed adress.

Comment: @AlpBaşar: It sounds to me like you are referring to consecutive executions of the program. Can you confirm that the output of `print pointer` (from `gdb` console) and the `printf(...)` output are different during the _same run of the program_?

Answer (score 2):

First, to answer your question:

> Shouldn't the adresses that the debugger gives and the program prints be the same?

The answer is yes, they should.  That is a requirement for reasonable debugging.

However, in practice, sometimes things can go awry.  For example, if your program relies on undefined behavior, then you can wind up with a situation where the compiler does one thing (say, takes a branch) but the debugger reports something else (printing the condition shows that it apparently should not have taken the branch).  Another reason for a discrepancy is a compiler bug; or an optimization that results in code apparently being executed out of order (i.e., you might see a variable's value change before or after you might expect).

What is most likely going on here, as the commenters pointed out, is address space randomization ("ASLR").  This is a security feature whereby the memory layout changes from run to run.  gdb disables this by default, but on most systems it is enabled by default outside of gdb.

So, for example, when I try your program on the console, I see different pointer values for each run:

```
$ ./q
value = 25
pointer = 0x7ffc7797716c
&pointer = 0x7ffc77977160
$ ./q
value = 25
pointer = 0x7ffd77b8199c
&pointer = 0x7ffd77b81990
```

So, what's important is to compare the values in gdb with the values printed by the same run in gcc.  This works fine for me:

```
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400542: file q.c, line 8.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/q 
value = 25
pointer = 0x7fffffffd8fc
&pointer = 0x7fffffffd8f0

Breakpoint 1, main () at q.c:8
8   }
(gdb) info local
value = 25
pointer = 0x7fffffffd8fc
(gdb) p &pointer
$1 = (int **) 0x7fffffffd8f0
```

Here you can see that the values are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but everytime I do debugging and directly print the results with the program, *pointer* is said to have the value `0xbffff834` with `printf`, and `0xbffff824` with GDB. So the problem is definetly not ASLR I did not know how the ASLR works by the way. Thank you for that.

Comment: Could be a compiler bug, but it's impossible to know without a pretty deep inspection.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Alp, thank you for the clarification.
re "why the same variable might have different addresses in *different* runs", I don't know a concise answer, that is something I need to do more research on.

original answer:
You wrote (emphasis added):

> ...and type print **pointer**, GDB gives me the result 0xbffff8**24**.  It also gives me 0xbffff8**20** when I type print **&pointer**. Shouldn't the adresses that the debugger gives and the program prints be the same?

As for your question, I agree with everyone they should be the same.
I can't tell if your question is comparing values from 2 different runs (one stand alone and one from within gdb).  As Jean-François Fabre commented, it is important to compare addresses within a single run so we'll do that here.

Your variable names are a little hard discuss as-is (they overload pointer and value), so here's an equivalent program.  I just used **v** for **value** and **p** instead of **pointer**.
Does the this accurately reflect what you were doing?

```
$ nl -b a bar.c
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 int main() {
  3    int v = 25;
  4    int *p = &v;
  5    printf("v=%d\n", v);
  6    printf("p=%p\n", p);
  7    printf("&p=%p\n", &p);
  8 }
  9
```

Setting a breakpoint on line 8 and running the program yields the following:

```
  $ gcc -g bar.c
  $ gdb a.out
      GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
      ...etc...
      Reading symbols from a.out...done.
      (gdb) break 8
      Breakpoint 1 at 0x400601: file bar.c, line 8.
      (gdb) r
      Starting program: /home/jgreve/stackoverflow/pointer_basar/a.out 
      v=25
(i)   p=0x7fffffffddfc
(ii)  &p=0x7fffffffde00

      Breakpoint 1, main () at bar.c:8
      8 }
      (gdb) print p
(iii) $1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffddfc
      (gdb) print &p
(iv)  $2 = (int **) 0x7fffffffde00
      (gdb) x/d p
(v)   0x7fffffffddfc:   25
      (gdb) quit
      A debugging session is active.

              Inferior 1 [process 10380] will be killed.

      Quit anyway? (y or n) y
      $
```

Note that (i) and (iii) are identical, they both show the address of **v** as 0x7fffffffdd**fc**.

Also (ii) and (iv) are identical, they both show the *address* of **p**, which is the same thing as **&p**, as 0x7fffffffde**00**.

In short, **print &p** doesn't give you the address of **v**, it is the *address* of **p**.
Since **v** and **p** are different variables they *must* have different addresses.

fwiw, (v) also shows the expected decimal value of **25**, the contents of memory location 0x7fffffffdd**fc** (e.g. the *address* **v**).

edit: My original an was a longish example talking about memory maps, then I killed it because I didn't think I understood your question.
Rereading the question more carefully makes me think I got it (mostly) right the first time, and that gdb is behaving as expected.  (this version is more clear)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I should be more clear with my question and I am sorry about that. I will edit it now. My question is not why &pointer and pointer are different, it is why (i) and (iii) are not the same when I run the program directly or look at the pointer with the print command of GDB for me. Since they both refer to the same pointer(the pointer named pointer in my case).